# Infinispan: What is the unit used for the cache_size metric?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, infinispan

When working with Infinispan metrics coming through Prometheus, we query the metrics using the following statement:

`sum by (pod, name) (cache_size{namespace=~”$namespace”, pod=~”$pod”, name=~”$cacheName”, cacheManager=~”$cacheManager”})`

We receive results, but what is the unit used for measuring the size of the cache? Is it KB, MB?

Answer (score 0):

According to the metric description:

```
# HELP cache_size The number of entries in this cache. This may be an approximation, depending on the type of cache.
# TYPE cache_size gauge
```

You can find this info in the HTTP page on the metrics exported to the Prometheus.